# How to deploy in Openshift Container Platform using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, openshift

I am new to Openshift Container Platform. I am trying to deploy my application which uses node, redis and mongo. I have written a Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. I am able to run it successfully in local system. Challenge I am facing is deploying in Openshift. Below are my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml:

Dockerfile:

```
# Install node v10
FROM node:10.16.3

RUN apt update && apt install -y openjdk-8-jdk

# Set the workdir /var/www/myapp
WORKDIR /var/www/myapp

# Copy the package.json to workdir
COPY package.json .

# Run npm install - install the npm dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy application source
COPY . .

# Copy .env.docker to workdir/.env - use the docker env
#COPY .env.docker ./.env

# Expose application ports - (4300 - for API and 4301 - for front end)
# EXPOSE 4300 4301
EXPOSE 52000

CMD node app.js
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    container_name: myapp
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '52000:52000'
      # - '8080:8080'
    #   - '4300:4300'
    #   - '4301:4301'
    links:
      - redis
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: myapp-mongo
    image: 'mongo:4'
    ports:
      - '28107:28107'
      # - '27017:27017'
  redis:
    container_name: myapp-redis
    image: 'redis:4.0.11'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use kompose (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/translate-compose-kubernetes/) to translate your docker-compose resource to k8s manifests. I don't think you can deploy compose files directly without usage of other tools first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Docker Swarm. If you are more familiar with docker-compose,
Have a look it this it might help (https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/).